# Can a PCIe 2.0 x16 fit into x16 PCIe slot?

Tags: graphics-card, pci

http://reviews.cnet.com/video-components/galaxy-geforce-gt610-graphics/4505-3025_7-35487730.html fit to ECS GeForce 6100 pm-m2 v2.0 ?